# Creating a keyboard shortcut for a pop in a web page php

Tags: web, popup, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to activate a popup when the user press a key board shortcut. Can you please tell me how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a javascript function. Take a look at onkeypress or onkeyup.

The best option is probably jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == x) {
    //do something, i.e. alert('popup');
  }
});

A few of the key codes:
Enter       13
Up arrow    38
Down arrow  40
Left arrow  37
Right arrow 39
Escape      27
Spacebar    32
Ctrl        17
Alt     18
Tab     9
Shift       16
Caps-lock   20
Windows key 91
Backspace   8
Home        36
End     35
Insert      45
Delete      46
```